# content of slick.js slide disappearing in mobile version

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js, slick.js

I am using some slick.js sliders in a fullpage.js slide and every time I slide to the fullpage slide with the slick slider on it or through the slick slider, its content suddenly disappears. I can still see it when the slider slides to the slide, but after the sliding is finished, it disappears. Has anybody had this issue and successfully solved it yet? Strangely, it only happens on the mobile version of the page I am writing.

Thanks!

Comment: please share your code?

Comment: when I put the code excerpt into a jsfiddle, it works..

Comment: okay, I found out, that it somehow has to do with the setting "dots: true" because when I delete that, it works. I need these dots though..

Comment: You should provide a reproduction of your issue or a link to it in jsfiddle or codepen.